# this is my php code to view multiple images from database.but i can only see one image in front end.please help me

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, image

```
<?php

$servername = "*****";
$username = "****";
$password = "";
$dbname = "****";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$product_id = intval($_GET['product_id']); 
// make sure its only an id (SQL Incjection problems)
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM product_gallery WHERE pid=$product_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo"<div class='tg-productbox'>";
        echo" <div id='tg-thumblider' class='tg-thumblider tg-productgalleryslider owl-carousel'>";
        echo"   <figure class='item'><img src='$row[product_image]' alt='image description'></figure>";
        echo" </div>";
        echo"   </div>";
        echo"   </div>";
    };
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This is my php code to view multiple images from database.but I can only see one image in front end.please help me..there is a main image and a slider to view to multiple images. It is similar to how we see product images in a shopping site

this is my php code to view multiple images from database.but i can only see one image in front end.please help me..there is a main image and a slider to view to multiple images.its is similar to how we see product images in a shopping site

Comment: are you getting a single item or multiple items in result array?

Comment: print_r($result)  to see if you are getting multiple results or single. i think you are getting single result

Comment: iam getting multiple items in result array.but only first image is displayed in the front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes**

1. Remove `id='tg-thumblider'` from `echo "<div id='tg-thumblider' class='tg-thumblider`. ID must need to be unique. According to the code provided, In `while loop`, every `<div>` will have same ID, which is wrong. So, either remove that ID or give some unique ID to each div.
2. Remove extra `echo "</div>";`
3. Remove `;` from closing of while loop.

**Code:**

```
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div class='tg-productbox'>";
      echo "<div class='tg-thumblider tg-productgalleryslider owl-carousel'>";
        echo "<figure class='item'><img src='".$row['product_image']."' alt='image description'></figure>";
      echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some other mistakes like one extra closing div in loop and semicolon  `};` which not necessary.

Try something like below if you are getting multiple records it will definitely work.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
extract($row);
    ?>
    <div class='tg-productbox'>
         <div id='tg-thumblider' class='tg-thumblider tg-productgalleryslider owl-carousel'>
              <figure class='item'>
                 <img src="<?php echo $product_image; ?>" alt="image description">
              </figure>
          </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: is pid is unique ? can you debug how many data are you getting ?